# Searching for a document format.. flowing layout + page control

Tags: version-control, document

I am bouncing around the idea of creating a custom document versioning system to use on business rule manuals. These manuals are broken up into outlined sections which contain one rule per section which are outlined in various ways (1.1, 1.2, etc). There are many manuals which contain the same rule for different locations in the country (down to the state/county level), however many locations will have different versions of the rules depending on business needs or whatnot.

My thought is to create a system which will manage versions of each section/rule separately. This would make the management of this mess much easier to maintain (think hundreds of manuals times hundreds of rules), and it would make fielding query requests from management much quicker.

Ok, it's a fairly easy and straightforward design to this point. Now for the monkey wrench. These rules are regulated by government agencies, so they must be submitted to and approved by state agencies. In doing this, many states require only the exact pages which are updated for each request to be submitted for approval. Once they are approved, these pages will get a new effective date and the rest of the manual will remain the same. There are business reasons for this process.

So my choice of document format has to allow for flowing layout much like Word, however I need to be able to programatically determine the page range of these sections and if changes or additions will cause a repagination.

The most complex layout will contain only tables, headers/footers, and a table of contents. I have thought about using OOXML, but I don't see a way to determine pagination without loading Word which is something I would prefer to avoid. I could create my own pagination algorithm, but that sounds a lot like reinventing the wheel.

Can anyone offer pointers to a solution whether it is an open document format, a book, or something else? Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a truly modular document, then [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) might be worth a look. You have all the rich formatting you need but it does need a bit of work. It really depends on who's doing the authoring and what tools they're comfortable using. DocBook is a rich mark-up language and you can do anything from work in the base plain text file or look at a number of WYSIWYG editors, e.g. [ArborText](http://www.ptc.com/products/arbortext/editor).

It's not Word though - which might be enough to put your authors off!

If you did go with DocBook, you would maintain each document section in a separate text file so your versioning solution would work well. DocBook can produce output in a number of formats simultaneously so you could have an HTML version, an OOXML version, and a PDF version produced from the same source. A PDF version of each changed section might be appropriate to send to government agencies for approval.

On pagination, you could make life a lot easier for yourself by not having continuous page numbers. Use section or chapter based page numbering, e.g. page I-1, I-2, ..., II-1, II-2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew that I would have to use markup or xml, and it is good to find something established. I think you would be correct about only sending comparisons of the sections involved without having to worry about showing the previous and next sections to give the illusion of a hard typed manual, however updates to the manuals are usually sent out to the field as replacement pages. It looks like a manual overhaul is in order. Thanks!